# UV Unwrapping doesn't appear to me. Is my file the problem?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, color, mixamo

[image: Chris Redfield Rigged]

Hello kind people! I'm totally new to Blender, have been watching tutorials and reading about it,  but right now I don't know what's going on.
After I did the autorigging in Mixamo, my character lost all its colors and textures, and I'm trying to give them back, but none of the options related to UV unwrapping appear, not even when I type it in the menu.
I don't know if the problem is in the file, nor have any idea what to do. Can someone please help me?

[image]

(Emir helped me with the first question <3 The other image is how it got after I corrected what he pointed out.)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. First of all, you are in object mode, switch to edit mode to see if that solves you UV problem, second of all, it appears that you are in solid mode, change that to (keyboard Z) material preview

Comment: THANK YOU! <3 That changed things for better now! But please, if you can, take a look at how it is, I posted a new image in the question. Do I have to add more textures?

Comment: Below your File menu on the side of your UV map view, there is an icon of two arrow it is used as a synchronization between the UV and the 3D object, click that to see your UV map, or just select all the vertices on your 3D object see this
https://youtu.be/mmYJWMP_M4E?si=nB_pAC2qNE41Wh5l&t=156

Comment: It worked! At least I think so haha, because the character now looks clean and colorful in the UV editing, but when I go back to the layout, it still metallic. Which one do I trust? (I've added another image to the question).